# How to get ios native actions sheet in react native

Tags: react-native

How to get ios native actions sheet in react native. like this image I am unable to find right library for this type of actions sheet.

example image:-
[Image from flutter actionsheet library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUqZv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `react-native-action-sheet` library it provides the same style in IOS and it has a customization option for android, so you can make it whatever you want.

[library](https://github.com/expo/react-native-action-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

import from react-native

```
import { ActionSheetIOS } from 'react-native';
```

and use

```
ActionSheetIOS.showActionSheetWithOptions(
{
    options: ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"],
},
buttonIndex => { // do your actions });
```